# Stopping Tumblr navigation from disappearing

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm looking to find a way to stop the navigation on my Tumblr blog from disappearing as you go forward on a page. I want to have both previous and next page links and images to appear. Here's what I have so far. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

```
{block:PreviousPage}
<a href="{PreviousPage}"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/mfk3qy0/h3ilwl5wj/forward.png"></a>
{/block:PreviousPage}
{block:NextPage}
<a href="{NextPage}"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/mfk3qy0/q1Jlwl5x5/back.png"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
```

Answer (score 0):

The links disappear because they don't render when there isn't a next or previous page to go to.

Remove the surrounding `block` declarations for the next and previous buttons and instead surround all four with `{block:Pagination}...{/block:Pagination}`. So no matter what, both the previous and next links will render.

Comment: Here's my address, http://rnill.tumblr.com/ - It beats me why pagination won't solve this...